# SQL How to count unique value in a column only once per person per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table the displays names of people who scan to a bar code.
They often scan to multiple bar codes per day and sometimes the same code on the same day.
I need to count the amount of scan types for each person each day.
The problem I am having is that I don't want to count the same bar code value for the one person each day.

Below is an example of the SQL table.

[image: Example SQL Table]

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT EVENTDATE, BARCODE, count(BARCODE) AMOUNT
from TIMESHEET
where EVENTDATE = '27-OCT-17' 
group by EVENTDATE, BARCODE
order by EVENTDATE, BARCODE
```

The result gives me a count of 5 but I want only 4 because there are two duplicate bar code scans for JOHN SMITH for the same day.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Store dates as dates, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the example query doesn't work is because you don't remove duplicates by name. To do this you have to take distinct values with name or group by everything in select statement.  For example, subquery the distinct combinations of EVENTDATE, NAME, BARCODE to remove duplicates - then count barcodes by eventdate.

```
SELECT dT.EVENTDATE
      ,dT.BARCODE
      ,COUNT(dT.BARCODE) AS TOTAL
  FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT EVENTDATE, NAME, BARCODE
         FROM TIMESHEET
         --WHERE EVENTDATE = '2017-10-27'  --if you really need to filter by date
                                           --otherwise will group by all dates
       ) AS dT
GROUP BY dT.EVENTDATE  
        ,dT.BARCODE
```

Comment: Thank you you all for your help. Zorkolot got it right!

Comment: So you say mine didnt get the same result? and without tne need of a subquery?

Answer (score 6):

Just count the `DISTINCT` names instead.

```
SELECT EVENTDATE, BARCODE, count(DISTINCT NAME) AMOUNT
from TIMESHEET
where EVENTDATE = '27-OCT-17' 
group by EVENTDATE, BARCODE
order by EVENTDATE, BARCODE;
```

But you should use some `name_id` instead of `name` because you can have 2 persons name `Jhon Smith`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want:

```
select EVENTDATE, NAME, count(DISTINCT BARCODE) as cnt
from TIMESHEET
where EVENTDATE = '27-OCT-17' 
group by EVENTDATE, NAME
order by EVENTDATE, NAME;
```

Comment: OP want result be 4 instead of 5.

Comment: In fact this returns the number of barcodes by person instead of the number of persons by barcode (the question is a bit ambiguous)